# How do I pass HTML input text into a JS variable?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input, prompt

So I have been working on a game where you have a input that prompts the actions you make. So I need to be able to put in it a JS var so I can print the input text on the page and have the computer respond and manipulate it if needed. Does anyone have a way I can do this? I hope you can help.

here is what I have so far

```
<p style="font-size:33px; color:red;"> Trapped in a Room</p>
<hr/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p id="comtxt">You wake up trapped in a room and need to find a way out.<br/>Use the input bar below as a action prompt.</p>
<p id="usertxt"></p>
<form script="answer();">
<input id="prompt" width="60" type="text">
<input id="sub" type="submit">
</form>
```

and then the javascript

```
 var prompt = getElementById("prompt");
var comtxt = getElementById("comtxt");
var sub = getElementById("sub");
var usertxt = getElementById("usertxt");
var answer = function() {
    usertxt = prompt;
}
```

sorry if the JS is hard to read...

Comment: Are you asking for `form_element.value`?

Comment: can you be a little more specific, your question is very general.  Also you would need to use javascript to capture the value from the form input something like document.querySelector("#pageToPrint").value once you have it you would want to create an printable page via a get or post method to another page or ajax if you don't want to redirect them to another page.

Comment: Ok.. Ok... I understand that I did not use a lot of detail and I fixed that. Now it is much more detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sender = document.getElementById("sub");

sender.addEventListener("click", setInputText, false);

function setInputText (){
    var inpTxt = document.getElementById("prompt").value;
    document.getElementById("usertxt").innerHTML = inpTxt;
};
```

Here the fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/7d8fH/8/

Comment: So I tried out the code you answered with but it did nothing. It stayed the same. Do you know why that happened?

Comment: Sorry i've seen your html now, i've edit my answer. Check it out